# Best approach for generating dates from an HTML Form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I get data from users through HTML and I have to generate a number of dates on differents periods of time.

What would be most performant?

Process the data with **JS** and then send it to server through hidden **HTML**
 
or
send it directly to server and process it on **PHP**.

An example of one of the things I have to do on this JS code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jfhartsock/cM3ZU/).

Thanks,

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
   var dat = new Date(this.valueOf())
   dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
   return dat;
```

}

```
function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
  var dateArray = new Array();
  var currentDate = startDate;
  while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    dateArray.push(currentDate)
    currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
  }
  return dateArray;
}

var dateArray = getDates(new Date(), (new Date()).addDays(2));
for (i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i ++ ) {
  alert (dateArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: If this info is going into the DB. I'd say AJAX and process it on the server.

Comment: Fallexe thinks it would be faster to process data on Client's side. Why do you think it's better to do it on server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a rapid, smooth response, process the dates on the client.

In general, do server-side validation for any data you are going to store on the server. It is easy for someone to send false data to your PHP script, even with client side validation.

Comment: If no one shows a better argument I'll choose your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
?>
```

You should make sure your server is configured correctly an use the code above with the correct time-zone. Use the **PHP** `getdate()` function which returns an easy to use associative array. Client-side is not reliable, since the user can adjust their system clock. Of course, you will have to take into account the users location to determine displayed time adjustments. You can use **Javascript**'s `navigator.geolocation` and the `google.maps` API to get the users position, but you may have to pay Google depending on your use.